# MySQL vs SQL Server 2008 R2 simple select query performance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Can anyone explain to me why there is a dramatic difference in performance between MySQL and SQL Server for this simple select statement?

```
SELECT email from Users WHERE id=1
```

Currently the database has just one table with 3 users.  MySQL time is on average 0.0003 while SQL Server is 0.05. Is this normal or the MSSQL server is not configured properly?

**EDIT:**
Both tables have the same structure, primary key is set to `id`, MySQL engine type is InnoDB.
I tried the query with `WITH(NOLOCK)` but the result is the same.

Comment: Do the tables have similar structure? Do both have a (PRIMARY KEY) index on `id`?

Comment: Yes, table structure is the same, PK is set on `id`

Comment: What engine type are you using for the MySQL table?

Comment: I suspect it might be due to the different way MySQL and MSSQL issue locks. InnoDB uses a technique called Consistent Nonlocking Reads which is supposed to be more lightweight(I have not gone into detail) than actually locking the row like MSSQL will do. COuld you try the query on MSSQL as follows: `SELECT email FROM Users WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE id=1` and compare. This is only a hunch though.

Comment: A interesting read on the InnoDB and locking/transactional model can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: I tried with `NOLOCK` already and it's the same

Comment: Might be interesting to try a query that accesses no data at all in both, such as `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: It's about the same speed in both

Comment: When you execute statement first time, time is higher, as execution plan is also made then. I am also not sure that you can directly compare those numbers (specially if they are small)- are you sure MySQL and SQL Server does measure them in the same way? Maybe you can try execute that in the same way for 1000000 times and compare then the results..

Comment: Try "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE email from Users WHERE id = 1" on MySQL and compare the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the servers of the same level of power? Hardware makes a difference, too. And are there roughly the same number of people accessing the db at the same time? Are any other applications using the same hardware (databases in general should not share servers with other applications).

Personally I wouldn't worry about this type of difference. If you want to see which is performing better, then add millions of records to the database and then test queries. Database in general all perform well with simple queries on tiny tables, even badly designed or incorrectly set up ones. To know if you will have a performance problem you need to test with large amounts of data and many simulataneous users on hardware similar to the one you will have in prod.

Comment: The problem was that MySQL server was running on localhost and MSSQL on another host and the benchmarking time measured included network latency... Since you were the closest with your answer, I accept it but would like to thank other folks for their input :) And yes, I was comparing platforms for a new project and tried first with a basic query...

Answer (score 1):

The issue with diagnosing low cost queries is that the fixed cost may swamp the variable costs. Not that I'm a MS-Fanboy, but I'm more familiar with MS-SQL, so I'll address that, primarily.

MS-SQL probably has more overhead for optimization and query parsing, which adds a fixed cost to the query when decising whether to use the index, looking at statistics, etc. MS-SQL also logs a lot of stuff about the query plan when it executes, and stores a lot of data for future optimization that adds overhead

This would all be helpful when the query takes a long time, but when benchmarking a single query, seems to show a slower result.

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that might affect that benchmark but the most significant is probably the way [MySQL caches queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).

When you run a query, MySQL will cache the text of the query *and the result*. When the same query is issued again it will simply return the result from cache and not actually run the query.

Another important factor is the SQL Server metric is the total elapsed time, not just the time it takes to seek to that record, or pull it from cache. In SQL Server, turning on `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` will break it down a little bit more but you're still not really comparing  like for like.

Finally, I'm not sure what the goal of this benchmarking is since that is an overly simplistic query. Are you comparing the platforms for a new project? What are your criteria for selection?